# JQUERY - stop slider at the end of the images

Tags: jquery, slider

I utilize this plugin for slider

site > http://basic-slider.com/documentation/
script > https://github.com/jcobb/basic-jquery-slider/blob/807132214df170e1726e05f272fb75649687f268/js/basic-jquery-slider.js

the basic configuration is with loop slider, without stop at the end of the images.
it's possible change/edit same parameters to allow this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously not

```
defaults = {
// Width + Height used to ensure consistency
                width: 700,
                height: 300,
// The type of animation (slide or fade)
                animation: 'fade',
                // The duration in ms of the transition between slides
                animationDuration: 450,
                // Automatically rotate through the slides
automatic: true,
// Delay in ms between auto rotation of the slides
                rotationSpeed: 4000,
// Pause the slider when any elements receive a hover event
                hoverPause: true,
// Show the manual slider controls
                showControls: true,
// Center the controls vertically
                centerControls: true,
// Text to display in next/prev buttons
                nextText: 'Next',
                prevText: 'Prev',
// Show positional markers
                showMarkers: true,
// Center the positional indicators
                centerMarkers: true,
// Allow navigation with arrow keys
                keyboardNav: true,
// Use image title text as caption
                useCaptions: true
            }
```

Also, that's not the idea of a slider, you probably should use a gallery plugin or something, maybe you'll find one here:  http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/

Comment: ok, but i can edit the js and change a part of script. i have to use this script. thanks 

https://github.com/jcobb/basic-jquery-slider/blob/807132214df170e1726e05f272fb75649687f268/js/basic-jquery-slider.js

Comment: What should your slider to when it gets to the last element during automated sliding? Go the other way? I think what you want is a gallery in which users can slide through elements but the elements don't slide by themselves. So that's not a slider, you really should think about getting a gallery plugin...